# Getting an error trying to use relationships in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.3, relationships

I am going crazy trying to figure this out. I swear it seems that I have everything set up correctly - yet I cannot for the life of me get my view to load without an error.

I have two database tables set up. The first is called "**foodItems**" and the second is called "**foodCategories**".

The **foodItems** table has the following columns:
id, uniqueID, categoryID, clientID, itemName, itemDescription, itemAlias, thumbURL, itemSize, itemCost, itemPrice, isTaxable, hasSizes, hasDescriptors, status, created_at, updated_at

The **foodCategories** table has the following columns:
id, uniqueID, clientID, categoryName, categoryAlias, status, created_at, updated_at

Next, I have two models, **FoodItem**, and **FoodCategory**.

The code I have in my **FoodItem** model looks like so:

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

     class FoodItem extends Model {
            protected $table = 'foodItems';

          public function foodCategory(){
                 return $this->belongsTo('App\FoodCategory');
            }
     }
```

The code in my **FoodCategory** model looks like so:

```
<?php
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class FoodCategory extends Model {
        protected $table = 'foodCategories';

        public function foodItem() {
                return $this->hasMany('App\FoodItem');
        }
    }
```

The code in my controller looks like this:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\FoodCategory;
    use App\FoodItem;

    class DashboardController extends Controller {

        public function __construct(){
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }

        public function food() {
            $food_items = FoodItem::orderBy('categoryID')->get();
            return view('food', compact('food_items'));
        }
    }
```

And finally, the code I have in my View (food.blade.php) is:

```
@foreach ($food_items as $food)
    <li>{{ $food->foodCategory->categoryName }}</li>
@endforeach
```

In my view, I have tried using parenthesis after "**foodCategory**", I have tried changing the name to "FoodCategory", "FoodCategory()", "foodCategories()", "foodCategories"... and about every other combination I can think of - but nothing seems to work.

As the code is right now, it produces the following error:

"Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Laravel/ChanceSystems2017/resources/views/food.blade.php)"

I'm really stumped at this point. Could anybody please shed some light onto what I am missing? Thank you!

Comment: You just need to verify that every `foodItem` has got a `foodCategory` associated with it. Check for those records in the database. You are getting the error as there is at least one `foodItem` without a `foodCategory`.

Comment: @linuxartisan I checked my DB, and all records in my foodItem table have a valid category_id. There are only 3 items in my foodItem's table, and only two possible categories that they could contain. I even ran the following code in my view:
foreach ($food_items as $food)
    <li>{{ $food->category_id }}</li>
endforeach

And it correctly displayed 3 list items, all with a valid category_id. So - back to being stumped :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public function foodCategory(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\FoodCategory', 'categoryID');
 }
```

And the inverse

```
public function foodItem() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\FoodItem', 'categoryID');
}
```

This is because you are not using the conventional `category_id`

Comment: I gave that a shot, but am still getting the following error.

"Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Laravel/ChanceSystems2017/resources/views/food.blade.php)"

Would modifying my two database tables to use "category_id" instead of uniqueID & categoryID fix this?

Comment: using `category_id` is just a convention. But it might help. What are your tables names ? try adding them in your model like this: `protected $table =  'foodCategories';`